# ruby remove backslash from string

Tags: ruby

How would I make this a regular string with no slash?

I have:

```
 "3e265629c7ff56a3a88505062dd526bd\""
```

I want:

```
"3e265629c7ff56a3a88505062dd526bd"
```

Comment: Do you mean no backslash and no double quote in the string? Because the backslash indicates that the following double quote is part of the string. But your example removes the trailing double quote from the string.

Comment: Slash is `/` and backslash is \. The difference might seem academic, but it's important as the two have a completely different meaning in Ruby.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have:

```
"3e265629c7ff56a3a88505062dd526bd\""
```

Is equivalent to:

```
'3e265629c7ff56a3a88505062dd526bd"'
```

So to remove that:

```
string.tr!('"', '')
```

Remember all special characters are prefixed with backslash. This includes not only things like newline `\n` or linefeed `\r`, but also quotation mark `"` or backslash itself `\\`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you use `tr` and not `sub` or `gsub`?

Comment: @spickermann It's because `tr` is really fast at removing or remapping characters. `gsub` will give you the same result, but it involves compiling and applying a regular expression and can't match the simplicity or speed of `tr`. For a single call, the difference is irrelevant, but within loops there's a huge payoff on `tr`.

Answer (score 5):

How is this?

```
s = "3e265629c7ff56a3a88505062dd526bd\""
s[/\w+/]
# => "3e265629c7ff56a3a88505062dd526bd"
```

Comment: Not many people know about `String#[]` with a regular expression so this is interesting.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete everything except letters and numbers you can use 'tr' function.

For example:

```
"3e265629c7ff56a3a88505062dd526bd\"".tr('^A-Za-z0-9','')
```

This function replace everything but letters and numbers with a string with no characters. [Here](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr) is a reference of the function.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Just another way `"3e265629c­7ff56a3a88­505062dd52­6bd\"".del­ete ?"`

Comment: This is the most straightforward answer, and is how I would answer. I wonder why later answers with more indirect ways needed to come up, and were even upvoted.

Comment: That's because I read this question a little late than others :D

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "3e265629c7ff56a3a88505062dd526bd\""
str.gsub(%r{\"}, '')
 => "3e265629c7ff56a3a88505062dd526bd"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) is your friend. Starting with:

```
foo = "3e...bd\""
```

These are alternate ways to get the value without the trailing embedded quote:

```
# delete it
foo[-1] = ''
foo['"'] = ''
foo[/"$/] = ''
```

Or:

```
# skip it
foo[0..-2]
```